# confuse with saving between previous value and current in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new in python, I try to make a simple python script that save a fluctuative value between previous value and current value. But I get confuse with that..

Let say that, a fluctuative value is position

previous_value = position

current_value = position

How to make previous value is saved before next position value ??

Answer (score 0):

```
previous_value,current_value = None,None  #initialize values outside the loop

for loop ... :
  previous_value = current_value   #storing last current value as previous value
  current_value = position         #storing current position as current value.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
previous_value, current_value = current_value, position
```

Answer (score 0):

Python assignments guarantee that you can use the same variable on the left and the right side of an assignment, and also allows to assign multiple values in a single statement:

```
previous, current = 0, 1
for i in range(10):
    previous, current = current, i
```